# DbVisualizer.rpm is not converting to .deb?

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, dbvisualizer

I am using latest updated version of UBUNTU 12 operating system.I downloaded DbVisualizer.rpm from [here](http://www.dbvis.com/download/).I tried to install DbVisualizer by converting .rpm into .deb format using the follwing command

```
$ sudo alien DbVisualizer.rpm
```

The above command line generating the following error message,

```
dpkg-gencontrol: error: syntax error in debian/control at line 11: continued value line not in field
dh_gencontrol: dpkg-gencontrol -ldebian/changelog -Tdebian/dbvis.substvars -Pdebian/dbvis returned exit code 25
make: *** [binary-arch] Error 25
```

and Other than DbVisualizer.rpm are all generating .deb successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seem to work with the latest DbVisualizer 9.1.x versions:

http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1420744.html